# Finding information about the combinatorial concepts (arriving from Music Theory)

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, cyclic-groups, music-theory

In my music theory PhD work on scales, I've come across certain classes of musical scales, which I believe might have parallels within mathematics and I hope you can help me learn more about these classes from a mathematical point of view (I am quite ignorant in Mathematics).

In my work, I represent scales as sets on a necklace of cardinality $12$. The nodes of the necklace are therefore marked $0$ through $11$.

Below is the set `[0 2 5 7 10]`

[image]

The structure can manifest in any of $12$ manifestations:
[image]

I have found (musically) that certain slices of a structure can reveal the different amounts of information about its rotation.

[image]

As you can see above, the combination `[0 2]` can appear in 3 of the 12 possible rotations of the scale, while the combination `[0 4]` can only appear in one rotation. Therefore, with respect to the set `[0 2 5 7 10]`, `[0 4]` is a:

*Diagnostic Combination*

The scale in question `[0 2 5 7 10]` has $7$ such diagnostic combinations:

```
[0 4]
[0 2 4]
[0 4 7] 
[0 4 9] 
[0 2 4 7]
[0 2 4 9] 
[0 4 7 9]
```

Since all of these combinations contain `[0 4]`, I say that `[0 4]` is the:

*Identity Fragment* for that set.

However, there are some sets that while they have Diagnostic Combinations, they don't have an identity fragment.
For instance, the set `[0 1 2 3 5]` has many diagnostic combinations (for instance `[0 1 5]` and `[0 2 3]`), but no fragment is common to them all. So this has no Identity fragment.

And yet, there's another class of sets, sets that have an Identity Fragment (a fragment that appears in all diagnostic combinations), but where the Identity Fragment in itself isn't diagnostic. Such an example is the set `[0 1 3 5 6 8 10]` where all the diagnostic combinations contain `[0 6]`, but `[0 6]` by itself is not diagnostic (has $2$ possible manifestations).

I am wondering if there's well-established work on similar concepts within math:

- a so-called Diagnostic Combination
- a so-called Identity Fragment
- And the cases where the Identity Fragment is and isn't also a diagnostic combination.

My gut is telling me that either Combinatorics, and / or Information Theory can help me deepen my exploration of those musical structures. Am I right?

Comment: Further to Vezen's answer, you might want to check out [the Wikipedia page on Root of unity - The $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity form a cyclic group.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Group_of_nth_roots_of_unity) and [a proof of this fact from the corresponding Wiki page](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Roots_of_Unity_under_Multiplication_form_Cyclic_Group).

Comment: Both the wiki entry and the proof are way above my pay grade, but I'll spend some time with them. Can you say in plain-English what the general principal of an "nth roots of unity"? lot's of jargon I don't know, but super curious!

Comment: Do you know [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Relation_to_Euler's_formula), @MichaelSeltenreich?

Comment: Now I do. This I can follow, but this is about as sophisticated as my poor math understanding can do.

Comment: So let $z = x + yi$ be a complex number.  (That is, let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.)  Then $z$ is an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity if $z^n = 1$.  Do you follow?

Comment: ah! Yes! Ok, this helps, thanks

Comment: For example, what are the solutions of $z^2 = 1$?  We have $z_1 = x_1 + {y_1}i = 1 = 1 + 0\cdot{i}$ or $z_2 = x_2 + {y_2}i = -1 = -1 + 0\cdot{i}$.  By equating real and imaginary parts, can you then plot the points $z_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ in the complex (i.e. $x$-$y$) plane?  Additionally, what do you notice about the location of the points $z_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ relative to each other?  Lastly, the points $z_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $z_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ satisfy $z^2 = 1$.  But the modulus of the complex number $z = x + yi$ is $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  Hence...?

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you, @MichaelSeltenreich.  =)

Comment: By consulting us, you risk alienating yourself from the music community.  That first pentatonic scale gave me the blues... and required an overblow on hole 6 to play.

Comment: Fair enough, even though, there's actually a lot of mathy papers about musical scales Jack Douthett writes a lot about this https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=q99kfOQAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=sra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the interesting sharing! In my understanding, this is apparently related to the cyclic group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) which focuses on a single point, while what you are interested in involves the combination of points.

I would like to formulate your problem as follows:
We call the set $\Omega = \{0, 1,2,3,...,11\}$ the *full set*,
and each subset $N \subset \Omega$ represents a *pattern*.
We always sort $N$ so that $N = \{0 \leq N_1 < N_2 < \ldots < N_{|N|} \leq 11\}$.

For the *Diagnostic Combination* (DC), let $DC(N)$ denote the set of Diagnostic Combination(s) of $N$.
Clearly, if $D$ is a DC of $N$, then $(D + x)\mod 12$ is also a DC of $N$, for any $x$.

Therefore, WLOG, we may assume that each element in $DC(N)$ contains $0$.
For the simplest case, two-element DCs, we first compute all the *pairwise distances* between the points in $N$ which is $(|N_j - N_i| \mod 12)_{i \neq j}$.
After that, immediately we may have DCs for each *unique* distance. (We need to be careful here, e.g., for the *equivalent* distances $x$ and $12 - x$. We just grab the general idea first.)
Now we always take closer distances. See the examples you have mentioned first.

(1) $N = \{0, 2,5,7,10\}$. The pairwise distances are
$$(2,5,5,2,3,5,4,2,5,3),$$
where $4$ is unique. Therefore, $\{0, 4\}$ is a DC of $N$.

(2) We generalize our preliminary idea and check the example $N = \{0,1,2,3,5\}$. Since you mentioned two *three-element* DCs, we shall check all tuplet-wise distances.

- $\{0,1,2\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 2)$
- $\{0,1,3\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 3)$
- $\{0,1,5\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 5)$
- $\{0,2,3\} \rightarrow (0, 2, 3)$
- $\{0,2,5\} \rightarrow (0, 2, 5)$
- $\{0,3,5\} \rightarrow (0, 3, 5)$
- $\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 2)$
- $\{1,2,5\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 4)$
- $\{1,3,5\} \rightarrow (0, 2, 4)$
- $\{2,3,5\} \rightarrow (0, 1, 3)$

We see that both $(0,1,5)$ and $(0,2,3)$ (and more) are unique. That's why both of them are DCs.

(3) For your last example $N = \{0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10\}$, $(0, 6)$ itself is special due to the equivalent distances we have mentioned above in that $12 -6 = 6$.

(4) Regarding the Identity Fragment (IF), we would like to answer first the question: what kinds of $N$'s have an IF?
Mathematically, $N$ has an IF if $DC(N)$ has a minimum set that is a subset of each element in $DC(N)$, i.e., the intersection of all DCs is also a DC.

(*) We also have a similar idea *Permutation Cycle* (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html). In a similar manner, I would like to call the term we are interested in *Cyclic Cycle*.

(**) In short, a DC is a set of points that can be perfectly matched only once when you rotate the necklace for a whole circle ($12$ steps). Therefore, I do believe that DCs reveal cyclic symmetry.

(***) We may also see the problem backward. We fix a set of points $D$ and study what kind of $N$'s have $D$ as the DC or IF.

(****) Since $2^{12}$ is small, I tried to enumerate all possible cases.
First I would like to point out that for $N = \{0, 2, 5, 7, 10\}$ the OP's statement needs to be clarified.
Specifically, $\{0, 4\}$ is not an IF strictly since e.g., $\{0,2,5,10\}$ is also a DC of this $N$, but $\{0,2,5,10\}$ is cyclically equivalent to $\{0,2,4,7\}$ by moving $10$ to $0$.
In my understanding, the OP's definition of IF is the maximal $\tilde{D}$ such that for each DC, there exists a cyclically equivalent one containing $\tilde{D}$.
Following this idea, I wrote the following code.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from itertools import chain, combinations, cycle
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np


def powerset(iterable):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482316/14709977
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))


N2subpatterns = defaultdict(list)
for N in tqdm(powerset(range(1, 12)), total=2 ** 11):  # we assume 0 is always in N
    N = np.append([0], N)
    for n in N:
        N_with_n_at_0 = (N - n) % 12
        for subp in powerset(np.setdiff1d(N_with_n_at_0, 0)):
            N2subpatterns[tuple(sorted(N.astype(int)))].append(tuple(np.append([0], sorted(subp)).astype(int)))

N2representative = dict()
representative2Ns = defaultdict(set)
# representative2Ns[N2representative[A]] is the equivalent class containing A
for N in tqdm(N2subpatterns):
    N_arr = np.array(N)
    repr_N = min([tuple(np.sort((N_arr - n) % 12)) for n in N_arr])
    N2representative[N] = repr_N
    representative2Ns[repr_N].add(N)

N2DCs = {N: [set(s) for s in subps if subps.count(s) == 1] for N, subps in N2subpatterns.items()}
for N, DCs in N2DCs.items():
    if not DCs:
        continue
    subps_of_DCs = []
    for DC in DCs:
        DC = tuple(sorted(DC))
        subps_DC = set.union(*[set(N2subpatterns[tuple(DC_eq)]) for DC_eq in representative2Ns[N2representative[DC]]])
        subps_of_DCs.append(subps_DC)
    IFs = set.intersection(*subps_of_DCs) - {(0,)}
    IFs = set(N2representative[IF] for IF in IFs)
    if len(IFs) == 1:
        IF = min(IFs)
        print(f'N = {N}')
        print(f'IF = {IF}')
        DC_reprs = set(N2representative[tuple(sorted(DC))] for DC in DCs)
        DC_eq_containing_IF = [tuple(sorted(DC)) for DC in DC_reprs if set(IF).issubset(set(DC))]
        print(f'DCs are {DC_eq_containing_IF}')
        print()
```

Below are the full results for all $N$'s with an IF (due to the length limit, please check https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XjAfKi6_hxUcu5QKdZIA2wi06u0s9z7JtkWk5mWlVPI/edit?usp=sharing):

```
N = (0, 1, 2)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 1, 2}]

N = (0, 1, 11)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 1, 2}]

N = (0, 2, 4)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}]

N = (0, 2, 7)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 2, 7}]

N = (0, 2, 10)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}]

N = (0, 5, 7)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 2, 7}]

N = (0, 5, 10)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 2, 7}]

N = (0, 8, 10)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}]

N = (0, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 2)
DCs are [{0, 2}, {0, 1, 2}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}]

N = (0, 1, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}]

N = (0, 2, 5, 7)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 10, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 2, 7, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 10, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 3, 5, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 10, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 5, 7, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 10, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 4, 5, 8)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5, 8}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4, 7}]

N = (0, 1, 4, 5, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 1, 4}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 9}, {0, 9, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5, 9}]

N = (0, 1, 4, 8, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 1, 4, 9}, {0, 1, 4, 8, 9}, {0, 9, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 5, 8, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 11, 4, 7}, {0, 4, 7, 8, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 1, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 2, 4, 7, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 9, 4, 7}, {0, 2, 4, 7, 9}]

N = (0, 2, 5, 7, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 9, 4, 7}, {0, 2, 4, 7, 9}]

N = (0, 2, 5, 7, 10)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 9, 4, 7}, {0, 2, 4, 7, 9}]

N = (0, 3, 4, 7, 8)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 3, 4, 7, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 3, 4}, {0, 11, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7, 11}]

N = (0, 3, 4, 8, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 11, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 8, 11}, {0, 11, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4}]

N = (0, 3, 5, 7, 10)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 9, 4, 7}, {0, 2, 4, 7, 9}]

N = (0, 3, 5, 8, 10)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 2, 4, 7}, {0, 9, 2, 4}, {0, 9, 4, 7}, {0, 2, 4, 7, 9}]

N = (0, 3, 7, 8, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 9, 4, 5}, {0, 4, 5, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 7}]

N = (0, 4, 5, 8, 9)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 9, 4, 5}, {0, 4, 5, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 4, 7}, {0, 11, 4}, {0, 3, 4, 7}]

N = (0, 4, 7, 8, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 11, 4, 7}, {0, 4, 7, 8, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 9, 4}, {0, 1, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 8, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 4)
DCs are [{0, 4}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 4}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 11)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 9}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 3, 5, 8, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 10, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 7, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 10}]

N = (0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 9, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {0, 10, 3, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 11, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 4, 7, 9, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 8, 3, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 8, 11}, {0, 3, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 10, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7, 10}]

N = (0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 11, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 8, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}]

N = (0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 11, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 6, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 9, 11}, {0, 2, 3, 6, 9, 11}, {0, 8, 3, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 8, 11}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 2, 4, 7, 9, 11)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 2, 5, 8, 9, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 10, 3, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 10}, {0, 3, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 11, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7, 9}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 8}]

N = (0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {0, 3, 5, 8, 9}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 7}]

N = (0, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10)
IF = (0, 1)
DCs are [{0, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 1, 8}, {0, 1, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 10, 5}, {0, 1, 10, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 5, 8, 10}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10}]

N = (0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 10, 3, 7}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 10}, {0, 3, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 7}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 11, 3, 5}]

N = (0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 8, 3, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 8, 11}, {0, 3, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 8, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 10, 3, 4}]

N = (0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 5)
DCs are [{0, 5}, {0, 1, 5}, {0, 2, 5}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
IF = (0, 6)
DCs are [{0, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 6}, {0, 3, 6}, {0, 4, 6}, {0, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 6}, {0, 1, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 5, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 6}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 5, 6}, {0, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11)
IF = (0, 6)
DCs are [{0, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6}, {0, 9, 6}, {0, 10, 6}, {0, 11, 6}, {0, 8, 6, 7}, {0, 9, 6, 7}, {0, 10, 6, 7}, {0, 11, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6, 9}, {0, 8, 10, 6}, {0, 8, 11, 6}, {0, 9, 10, 6}, {0, 9, 11, 6}, {0, 10, 11, 6}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 6)
DCs are [{0, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6}, {0, 9, 6}, {0, 10, 6}, {0, 11, 6}, {0, 8, 6, 7}, {0, 9, 6, 7}, {0, 10, 6, 7}, {0, 11, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6, 9}, {0, 8, 10, 6}, {0, 8, 11, 6}, {0, 9, 10, 6}, {0, 9, 11, 6}, {0, 10, 11, 6}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 6}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 6}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 6}, {0, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 3, 6}, {0, 8, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 6}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {0, 2, 3, 6, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 11, 3, 4}, {0, 10, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 10, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 9, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 9, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 3, 7}, {0, 9, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 3, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 9}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 9}, {0, 1, 3, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 7, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 8, 9}, {0, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 11, 3, 4}, {0, 10, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 10, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11)
IF = (0, 6)
DCs are [{0, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6}, {0, 9, 6}, {0, 10, 6}, {0, 11, 6}, {0, 8, 6, 7}, {0, 9, 6, 7}, {0, 10, 6, 7}, {0, 11, 6, 7}, {0, 8, 6, 9}, {0, 8, 10, 6}, {0, 8, 11, 6}, {0, 9, 10, 6}, {0, 9, 11, 6}, {0, 10, 11, 6}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}]

N = (0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8)
IF = (0, 3)
DCs are [{0, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 5}, {0, 3, 6}, {0, 10, 3}, {0, 11, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 3, 4, 6}, {0, 10, 3, 4}, {0, 11, 3, 4}, {0, 3, 5, 6}, {0, 10, 3, 5}, {0, 11, 3, 5}, {0, 10, 3, 6}, {0, 11, 3, 6}, {0, 11, 10, 3}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 10}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 6, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11}, {0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 3}, {0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 3, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 8, 2, 3}, {0, 8, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 8}, {0, 1, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 2, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for formalizing my question and adding some information. Also many thanks for showing how to identify DCs. However, I'm less interested in an algorithm. Rather, I'd like to know know if from a mathematical standpoint I can stand to learn anything about those DCs that I didn't already reveal musically. Does the number of elements necessary for a DC reveal something about the set? Does this say anything about compressibility of the necklace or anything coming from Information Theory? What can I learn about those classes of sets mathematically? Hope I'm not being too vague.

Comment: The Permutation Cycle stuff is very interesting!

Comment: In short, a DC is a set of points that can be perfectly matched only once when you rotate the necklace for a whole circle (12 steps). Therefore, I do believe that DCs reveal cyclic symmetry.

Comment: Anything interesting about "Identity Fragments" or when the Identity Fragment is and isn't diagnostic? That is, I find it interesting (but perhaps trivial) that in some sets like 0 2 5 7 10 DCs must contain 0 4. But other sets like 0 1 2 3 5, do not have any sense of self-similarity between them. Not sure if it's a thing.

Comment: About the identity fragment: Consider the set [0 3 4 7 8]. Every DC of that set contains [0 4] (an interval of size 4), but [0 4] itself, isn't diagnostic. There's many examples that aren't [0 6]. [0 4] would also be an IF for [0 1 4 5 8]

Comment: Check my last point, namely (****)

Comment: I show a counterexample in (****). For your statement, do you mean that {0, 2, 5, 10} should be expressed as {0, 2, 4, 7}?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134102/discussion-between-vezen-bu-and-michael-seltenreich).